# SQL Server - wrong execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have a very big table with a lot of rows and a lot of columns (I know it's bad but let's leave this aside).

Specifically, I had two columns - `FinishTime, JobId`. The first one is the finish time of the row and the second is its id (not unique, but almost unique - only few records exist with the same id).

I have index on jobid and index on finishtime.

We insert rows all the time, mostly ordered by the finish time. We also update statistics of each index periodically.

Now to the problem:

When I run query with filter `jobid==<some id> AND finishtime > <now minus 1 hour>` - this query takes a lot of time, and when showing the estimated execution plan I see that the plan is to go over the `finishtime` index, even though going over the `jobid` index should be a lot better. When looking at the index statistics, I see that the server "thinks" that the number of jobs in the last hour is 1 because we didn't update the statistics of this index.

When I run query with filter `jobid==<some id> AND finishtime > <now minus 100 days>` - this works great, because the SQL Server knows to go over the correct index - the job id index.

So basically my question is why if we don't update index statistics all the time (which is time consuming), the server assumes that the number of records past the last bucket is 1?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a histogram of what the statistics contains for an index using [DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384.aspx), e.g.

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ( mytablename , myindexname )
```

For date-based records, queries will always be prone to incorrect statistics.  Running this should show that the last bucket in the histogram has barely any records in the range [prior-to-today / after-today].  However, all else being equal, SQL Server should still prefer the `job_id` index to the `finishtime` index if both are single-column indexes with no included columns; this is due to job_id (int) being faster to lookup than finishtime (datetime).

Note: If your `finishtime` is covering for the query, this will heavily influence the query optimizer in selecting it since it eliminates a bookmark lookup operation.

To combat this, either

1. update statistics regularly
2. create multiple filtered indexes (2008+ feature) on the data, with one partition updated far more regularly being the tail end
3. use index hints on sensitive queries

Comment: Well you explained the issue, but I don't understand what can I do about it? I have instructed my users to user very old finish time when they query for specific job id at the moment

Comment: If you know the main SPs that use the date filter in tandem with job id, add an index hint

Comment: why does the SQL server thinks the number of rows past the last bucket is 1 and not for example average of buckets? I consider this to be some kind of bug. Anyway, helpful tips. Thanks!